# If consecutive dataframe values are equal, edit value of second column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to identify consecutive column values that are the same, and when they are, edit a second column to give their rows more 'uniqueness'.

Given the following dataframe

```
name    code
Jim      G
Jim      G
Bob      F
Abe      Z


if df['name'] == df.shift()['name']:
    num = 1
    df['code'].loc() = df['code'] + '_' + num
    num +=
    df['code'].loc().shift() = df['code'] + '_' + num
```

The target output is:

```
name    code
Jim      G_1
Jim      G_2
Bob      F
Abe      Z
```

Comment: Pro-tip, if these columns are supposed to be the index, you can use `df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)` (I know it doesn't answer this question but I feel like this could be an XY problem).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, in this case they are not the index :)

Comment: In general, it would be helpful to see more rows with data, and also some unique rows so we understand what the output should look like for non-duplicate columns.

Comment: Do you have, in addition with the above rows, a row with `Jim F`?

Comment: `df.code=np.where(g.code.transform('count').gt(1),df.code+'_'+g.cumcount().add(1).astype(str),df.code)
`

Comment: @QuangHoang this case would not happen

Comment: @WeNYoBen post an answer, cannot find a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

Do is as below

```
g=df.groupby('name')
df.code=np.where(g.code.transform('count').gt(1),df.code+'_'+g.cumcount().add(1).astype(str),df.code)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**:
the original assumes `name` and `code` got same numbers of duplicates as in the sample data. If they are different and want to enumerate `code` values by group of `name`, just need to groupby both `name` and `code` and `duplicated` on subset `['name', 'code']` as follows:

```
m = df.code + '_' + df.groupby(['name','code']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df.code.mask(df.duplicated(subset=['name','code'], keep=False), m)
```

---

**Original**:
I would use `duplicated` to flag `True` rows and using `.mask`

```
m = df.code + '_' + df.groupby(df.code).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df.code.mask(df.code.duplicated(keep=False), m)

Out[1876]:
0    G_1
1    G_2
2      F
3      Z
Name: code, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

#### IIUC

```
d0 = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
d0 = d0.assign(code=lambda d: d.code.str.cat(np.arange(len(d)).astype(str), sep='_'))
d0.combine_first(df)

  name code
0  Jim  G_0
1  Jim  G_1
2  Bob    F
3  Abe    Z
```